# JPanel Snapshot and save the image in a file.It shows black image.what to do?

Tags: java, file, jpanel, bufferedimage, snapshot

```
BufferedImage image=null;
            try {
                image = new BufferedImage(mypanel.getSize().width, mypanel.getSize().height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            } catch (HeadlessException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("D://end12.png"));
            } catch (IOException ef) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ef.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to save a panel image to file.when trying to do so.it shows a black image.which i do understandard is the background color for jpanel by default.But i have a colored jpanel.Can any one help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an empty `BufferedImage`, to paint the `Jpanel` on it use:

```
  try {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(mypanel.getWidth(),
                mypanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        mypanel.printAll(g);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("img.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Use print or printAll instead of paint as it doesn't use double buffering, better performance, and doesn't really on native attachment. You should also dispose of graphics context when you're done with it ;)

Comment: Yep +1, much better ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i need 15 reputation to up the answers..i have only 9 tilll now

Comment: @user3678399 See the little outline of a tick, next to the answer? Click that, it will accept the answer as been correct and close the question